# Error in setting emscripten compiler with qt creator

Tags: c++, qt5, qt-creator, emscripten

I am new to QT and emscripten.
I am writing code that uses QtCore apis. I need to port this C++ code to web using emscripten.
On windows, I am facing issues to build QT from source using emscripten and also building my project for webassembly.
I created a project in QT creator. I need to configure QT creator so that I can build my C++ code into wasm and port the api(s) for use on web.

On reading the QT documentation, https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-setup-webassembly.html, I have following issues in the setup:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnPxP.jpg]

For the compiler selection, I should be able to select Emscripten compiler but the option is only **available for C++.**

I have used QT web installer to install QT webassembly binaries, QT creator, mingw. I have installed **sed** too. Following are the locations:

QT:`C:\qt_webass\`

MinGW: `C:\qt_webass\Tools\mingw810_64`

Sed: `C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32`

Emscripten: `D:\src\webass\thirdparty\emsdk`

Following is the settings in the path variables:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/73VDU.jpg]

Not sure, now how to proceed and generate the wasm file for my QT project. Appreciate your help.

Thanks,
Ronak